# Javascript Variables to PHP Script

Tags: php, javascript, variables, character-encoding

I could see that this question was being asked a lot of times and I did extensive research on what methods could be used to transfer a couple of Javascript variables to a PHP script.

1. Post data in a form as hidden values
2. Post to URL, i.e. '/txt.php?h=' + var
3. Use a cookie

I'm trying write a piece of code that will let you download what you've written in [Wrrrite.com](http://wrrrite.com) - I'm the developer of this website. (I also did a client-side approach of putting the variables into the URI and setting a header to download stuff)

None of this is working. Either there's a character that's causing an error, or there are html elements.

Is there something I can code to guarantee a 1:1 transfer of the work/variables?

Datatype: HTML + various different Characters "!§!' etc.
Output: .txt File, perferably a 1:1 translation of what was being written on the form

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to transfer? If it's HTML, posting data in a form as hidden values should work. (So should an Ajax POST request.)

Comment: What does PHP has to do with this? Wrrrite appears to be written entirely in JavaScript and stores data using Local Storage (which makes "downloading" an impossibility, since the data is already local).

Comment: What code do you have? What "isn't working"? What errors do you get?

Comment: It is getting down voted because it can't be sensibly answered in its current form. What code have you got? Are you writing PHP? Are you writing JS? Both? How are you executing them? What errors do you get? What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @Quentin I'm writing both. I can execute them both, also. Not working means that random characters (since everything is allowed, including " ' [ ] ) ) will break the script.

Comment: How does it break them? Does the JavaScript error? Does the PHP error? How is the JS communicating with the PHP? If you watch the data in transit does it look right? How are you interacting with Wrrrite.com?

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I don't get what you are asking. I'm looking for the right way of going about transferring a variable with various characters, like html ' ; @, form point A (javascript) to B (PHP). I am the developer of Wrrrite

Comment: It might have helped if you'd mentioned that up front. So what code do you have to send the data to the server? What server side code do you have to process it? What error messages do you get?

Comment: @Quentin I'm fine with the server side code, but I'm unfamiliar with Javascript. Here's the Cookie Approach, which doesn't work http://pastebin.com/SKNtxLi5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should maybe use a Base64 encoding of your data, before sending it. Have a look at [MDN for the JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa) part and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) for the PHP decoding. This should prevent special characters from breaking your code.

Comment: Base64 inflates the data volume by 33% and shouldn't be necessary when POST is being used.

Comment: He states that his problems are special characters and html elements within the data. Both can be circumvented by Base64.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary when the content is only text, which it appears to be from a glance at the site in the question. encodeUriComponent is a more sensible approach.

Comment: @Sirko sure they can, but I can't think of a situation where it's *necessary* when POST is used.

Comment: How would I dynamically update the value of what is being submitted, since the user will change the text constantly?

Comment: You would just encode it in the moment it has to be transmitted to the server. Constant updating should not be necessary (and is to be avoided due to performance aspects).

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
//PHP

 if(isset($_REQUST['submit']))
{
  $download=$_REQUEST['download'];
// from database get value of all the downloadable items
// and check if the input is in that array then to the suitable thing. 
}
//HTML
<form method="post" action=''>
Type :<input type="text" id="txtField" name="txtField" />
<input type="hidden" name='download' />
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return onSubmit() " />
</form>

//Javascript

<script type="text/javascript">
function onSubmit()
{
if(document.getElementById("txtField").value != '')
{
  document.getElementById("download").value=document.getElementById("txtField").value;
return true;
}
else
{
 alert("Please enter item to download");
return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here's the Cookie Approach, which doesn't work http://pastebin.com/SKNtxLi5

That just slaps values together without any consideration for the data format used in cookies.

Quirks Mode has a [decent guide to cookies with JS](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) if you want to fix that.

However… the point of cookies is that the data persists. It isn't a sensible transform for one shot messages.